# Android Dialog Showing in 2 activities instead of one

Tags: android, dialog, this, android-context

I am relatively new to android studio and I have a problem with Dialog box. I want to display a Dialog box once after the application is installed in my profile_activity. However it shows up in the Main Activity afterwards and I believe it has something to do with the context as in the MainActivity I am passing the context of it into static class. Here's the code I`d really appreciate it if someone could explain why is that and if there's a way to fix this. This is the MainActivity which extends the profile_activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends profile_activity {
private static Context mContext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
    //---Setting property for greeting message and styling it a bit---//
    TextView textOut;
    textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textOut.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    textOut.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textOut.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
    textOut.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
    textOut.setText("Hello " + editText.getText() + ", pick one of the zodiac symbols below " +
            "to find out what the stars are holding for you today!");
    //---Initiallize properties for all of the buttons used in the Main Activity Page ---/
    ImageButton aquaButton;
    aquaButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bAquarius);
    ImageButton piscesButton;
    piscesButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bPisces);
    ImageButton ariesButton;
    ariesButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bAries);
    ImageButton taurusButton;
    taurusButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bTaurs);
    ImageButton geminiButton;
    geminiButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bGemini);
    ImageButton cancerButton;
    cancerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bCancer);
    ImageButton leoButton;
    leoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bLeo);
    ImageButton virgoButton;
    virgoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bVirgo);
    ImageButton libraButton;
    libraButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bLibra);
    ImageButton scorpioButton;
    scorpioButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bScorpio);
    ImageButton sagittariusButton;
    sagittariusButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bSagittarius);
    ImageButton capriButton;
    capriButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bCapricorn);

    //---Setting actions for each button when pressed---/

    aquaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent aquaActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    aqua_Activity.class);
            startActivity(aquaActivity);
        }
    });
    piscesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent piscesActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    pisces_activity.class);
            startActivity(piscesActivity);
        }
    });
    ariesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent ariesActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    aries_activity.class);
            startActivity(ariesActivity);
        }
    });
    taurusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent taurusActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    taurus_activity.class);
            startActivity(taurusActivity);
        }
    });
    geminiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent geminiActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    gemini_activity.class);
            startActivity(geminiActivity);
        }
    });
    cancerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent cancerActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    cancer_activity.class);
            startActivity(cancerActivity);
        }
    });
    leoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent leoActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    leo_activity.class);
            startActivity(leoActivity);
        }
    });
    virgoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent virgoActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    virgo_activity.class);
            startActivity(virgoActivity);
        }
    });
    libraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent libraActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    libra_activity.class);
            startActivity(libraActivity);
        }
    });
    scorpioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent scorpioActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    scorpio_activity.class);
            startActivity(scorpioActivity);
        }
    });
    sagittariusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent sagittActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    sagittarius_activity.class);
            startActivity(sagittActivity);
        }
    });
    capriButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent capriActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    capricorn_activity.class);
            startActivity(capriActivity);
        }
    });


}
//--Initializing static methods for navigation--//
private static void goToCapriAct() {
    Intent capriacti = new Intent(mContext, capricorn_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(capriacti);
}
private static void goToAquaAct() {
    Intent aquaacti = new Intent(mContext, aqua_Activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(aquaacti);
}
private static void goToPiscAct() {
    Intent piscacti = new Intent(mContext, pisces_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(piscacti);
}
private static void goToAriesAct() {
    Intent ariesacti = new Intent(mContext, aries_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(ariesacti);
}
private static void goToTaurAct() {
    Intent taursacti = new Intent(mContext, taurus_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(taursacti);
}
private static void goToGeminiAct() {
    Intent geminiacti = new Intent(mContext, gemini_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(geminiacti);
}
private static void goToCancAct() {
    Intent cancacti = new Intent(mContext, cancer_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(cancacti);
}
private static void goToLeoAct() {
    Intent leoacti = new Intent(mContext, leo_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(leoacti);
}
private static void goToVirgoAct() {
    Intent virgoacti = new Intent(mContext, virgo_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(virgoacti);
}
private static void goToLibraAct() {
    Intent libraacti = new Intent(mContext, libra_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(libraacti);
}
private static void goToScorpAct() {
    Intent scorpacti = new Intent(mContext, scorpio_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(scorpacti);
}
private static void goToSaggAct() {
    Intent saggacti = new Intent(mContext, sagittarius_activity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(saggacti);
}

//--Setting DatePickerFragment--//
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

        int year = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance o f DatePickerDialog and return it
        int theme;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) theme = AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK;
        else theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog;
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), theme, this, year, month, day);

    }

    //--Checks about every single sign and navigation--//
    String message;
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        month = month + 1;
        if ((month == 12 && day >= 22 && day <= 31) || (month == 1 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)){
            goToCapriAct();
            }
        else if ((month == 1 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month == 2 && day >= 1 && day <= 17)){
            goToAquaAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 2 && day >= 18 && day <= 29) || (month == 3 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
            goToPiscAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 3 && day >= 20 && day <= 31) || (month == 4 && day >= 1 && day <= 19)) {
            goToAriesAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 4 && day >= 20 && day <= 30) || (month == 5 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
            goToTaurAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 5 && day >= 21 && day <= 31) || (month == 6 && day >= 1 && day <= 20)) {
            goToGeminiAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 6 && day >= 21 && day <= 30) || (month == 7 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            goToCancAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 7 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 8 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            goToLeoAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 8 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 9 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            goToVirgoAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 9 && day >= 23 && day <= 30) || (month == 10 && day >= 1 && day <= 22)) {
            goToLibraAct();
        }
        else if ((month == 10 && day >= 23 && day <= 31) || (month == 11 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
            goToScorpAct();}
        else if ((month == 11 && day >= 22 && day <= 30) || (month == 12 && day >= 1 && day <= 21)) {
            goToSaggAct();}
        else
        {   System.out.println("Illegal date");}
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new MainActivity.DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public View.OnClickListener exitButtonLitener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        notificationcall();
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
};
public View.OnClickListener aboutButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent about_activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                aboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(about_activity);
    }
};

public void makeTag(String tag) {
    String or = savedname.getString(tag, null);
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedname.edit();
    preferencesEditor.putString("tag", tag);
    preferencesEditor.apply();
}

public View.OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //---Setting requirements for editText property---//
        if (editText.getText().length() > 0) {
            makeTag(editText.getText().toString());
            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                    .hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            Intent main_activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(main_activity);
        }


    }
};}
```

and here is the profile_activity:

```
public class profile_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
//---Setting public proerty for variables inherited in Main Activity---//
private Context cnt;
private String m_Text = "";
public EditText editText;
SharedPreferences savedname;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_activity);
    cnt = this;

    if(isFirstTime()){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(profile_activity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Title");

    // Set up the input
   final EditText input = new EditText(cnt);
    // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
   builder.setView(input);

    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            m_Text = input.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.show();}

    //---Initiallizing the properties used in profile activity---//
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    savedname = getSharedPreferences("notes", MODE_PRIVATE);
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);

    editText.setText(savedname.getString("tag",null));
    //---Initiallizing functions for each button--//
    btn1.setOnClickListener(saveButtonListener);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(aboutButtonListener);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(exitButtonLitener);


}
//---Creating public function for notifications---//

public void notificationcall(){
    //---Setting parameters to the notification---//
    NotificationCompat.Builder notifBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificaion_icon)
            .setTicker("Alert New Message")
            .setContentTitle("Goodbye!")
            .setContentText("It was nice having you today! Come back tomorrow for your new horoscope!")
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    //---Giving funcionality to the notification---//
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    //---Back stack supporting navigation of the notification---//
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    notifBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    //---Building the application---//
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notifBuilder.build());


}

private boolean isFirstTime()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (!ranBefore) {
        // first time
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.apply();
    }
    return !ranBefore;
}
        public View.OnClickListener exitButtonLitener = new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    notificationcall();
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
        };
        public View.OnClickListener aboutButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Intent about_activity = new Intent (profile_activity.this,
                            aboutActivity.class);
                    startActivity(about_activity);
                }
        };
        public void makeTag(String tag){
            String or = savedname.getString(tag, null);
            SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedname.edit();
            preferencesEditor.putString("tag",tag);
            preferencesEditor.apply();
        }

        public View.OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //---Setting requirements for editText property---//
                if (editText.getText().length()>0){
                    makeTag(editText.getText().toString());
                    ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                            .hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(),0);
                Intent main_activity = new Intent(profile_activity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(main_activity);
        }



    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity` class inside the `onCreate()` method you have `super.OnCreate()` call. So when your `profile_activity` is called it's `onCreate()` gets executed once, then comes the call from `MainActivity` call. That's why you are getting 2 dialog boxes instead of once. Because of the `AlertDialog.Builder object.show()` is inside `profile_activity` `onCreate()`.

So if you remove the `super` call from MainActivity's `onCrreate()`, it should resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes but when I remove the super class I get error which states that the onCreate should have a super class